Convert PWM negative signal to either On or Off signal
I am trying to make a simple conversion circuit to take a negative PWM signal from my cars dome lamp signal and simply make it or or off. I believe I should be able to use a PNP transistor and capacitor resistor combination, but not sure how to wire. Can anyone provide a basic circuit to do this? My goal is not to make a varying voltage of the PWM signal but rather, if the PWM is present, turn on the PNP with constant on, if the PWM signal is not present. The transistor is off. Simple on of switch based off of the negative PWM signal being present or not. Any help appreciated.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Document the pwm signal thoroughly and what distinguishes "present" from "not present".
